# Devise - sign in by email OR username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've done all of the this tutorial: [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

But when I try to log in I get error in the browser:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.login: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."login" = 'jan12345' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Where could be a problem? How to debug this?

I don't have `login` field on the `users` table but I have `username` field.

My model file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  attr_accessor :login
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :expiration_date) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a `login` column in `User` model ? I think no, but you confirm it first.

Comment: No. But I have `attr_accessor :login` in model file (like in the tutorial).

Comment: remove the `login` field from there `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }` then

Comment: Thanks, I removed. Now I have got this: `{ |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }`
But problem is the same.

Comment: You need to add login again to the sanitizer, the model is the issue

Comment: @Jensky I don't know then. I never needed `login` field. You will sanitize the DB fields, if you have. If you need then you need add it there.

Comment: @Jensky Do you really need the that many fields to signup/signin ? Or you just following the wiki even if you don't need it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending the `login` attribute to the db; you need to make it either `username` or `email`, which is done with a combination of both a custom attribute & special lookup, [as per the docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#create-a-login-virtual-attribute-in-the-user-model):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #remove attr_accessor :login (it just makes getter/setter methods which we do manually below)

  protected

  def login=(login)
    @login = login
  end

  def login
    @login || self.username || self.email
  end

  private

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
         where(conditions.to_h).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
         where(conditions.to_h).first
      end
  end
end
```

--

You've done a great job with the sanitizer etc -- what you're doing is taking a single "login" attribute & making Devise use *either* `login`, `username` or `email` to find the `User` record.

At present, the error says `users.login` cannot be found -- this means your `Devise` install is looking up `login` (which isn't in your database), when it should be searching through `username` and `email` WITH the `login` attribute.

The second bit of code (`self.find_for_database_authentication`) performs a lookup for `Devise`. If you read the query, it takes the `login` *attribute* and sets it to looking up *either* `username` or `email`. This is missing from your implementation and should be added.

After adding, remember to restart your server.

---

**Update**

Your [`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) should be in your *model* (yours is in your controller).

All it does is define a `setter` and `getter` method for the attribute you define. It's most commonly referred to as a ["virtual" attribute](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes), as it's not saved in the database.

I could tell you about `setter` / `getter` methods if required, I'll leave it for now to prevent confusion

Comment: Perfect. Works. Now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your initializer/devise.rb , write the below code:

config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]

In application controller , write the below code:

```
 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username) }
 end
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to log in by username OR email. Not only by username.

Comment: ok , no problem , write the code config.authentication_keys = [ :username , :email]

Comment: Also , allow email for login in above controller like  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit[:username, :email] }

Comment: Thanks. And what about views? I mean registration form. In Devise wiki I see this code: `= f.text_field :login`.
Because I have only one field for email OR login.

Comment: if u want to login by username then, write like f.text_field : username , but if u want to login by both , then follow the below "Rich Peck " approach

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do that much code,

You can check from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55184048/9490901 ,

only replace contact_number to username :